# "Notice: Undefined property:" al tratar de conectar a la base de datos

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente error con la conexión al tratar de acceder al contenido de la base de datos:

> Notice: Undefined property: Database::$host in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\TotalAgro\core\controller\Database.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined property: Database::$user in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\TotalAgro\core\controller\Database.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined property: Database::$pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\TotalAgro\core\controller\Database.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined property: Database::$ddbb in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\TotalAgro\core\controller\Database.php on line 10

Este es el código:

```
class Database {
    public static $db;
    public static $con;
    function _construct(){
        $this->user="root";$this->pass="";$this->host="localhost";$this->ddbb="totalagro";
    }

    function connect(){
        $con = new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->ddbb);
        return $con;
    }

    public static function getCon(){
        if(self::$con==null && self::$db==null){
            self::$db = new Database();
            self::$con = self::$db->connect();
        }
        return self::$con;
    }
```

Si tiene el formato *PHP*, solo que cuando subí la pregunta se me combinaba texto con código.

Comment: Anexo al error de sintaxis te recomiendo repases como se acceden a las propiedades estáticas, en especial presta atención a **`$con`** en el método connect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, algunas recomendaciones:
puedes usar un estilo multi-línea para setear las propiedades en el constructor, tambiénpara pasar parámetros, esto te permite ver mejor los cambios en sistemas de control de versiones como *Git*, además se recomienda que las líneas no excedan de 72 caracteres y máximo de 80, entonces para el constructor:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->user = "root";
    $this->pass = "";
    $this->host = "localhost";
    $this->ddbb = "totalagro";
}
```

y la función `connect()`:

```
function connect()
{
    $con = new mysqli(
        $this->host,
        $this->user,
        $this->pass,
        $this->ddbb
    );

    return $con;
}
```

Con esto puedes "detectar" con más facilidad el error que se producto a nivel de línea, normalmente una propiedad no estará definida, aunque en tu caso ninguna de las que te indica lo están.

Tu error es que **el *contructor* lleva delante dos guiones bajos y no uno**, entonces al instanciar la clase no estas seteando las propiedades. Llamas a un constructor que existe por defecto pero en este caso no hace nada.

Comment: Es usted un genio señor, no me había fijado en ese guión, muchas gracias